# Android Studio ZXsing QR SCANNER not working

Tags: android-studio, zxing, barcode-scanner

So I've been doing this for 2 days still it won't work. I tried some github advises and those on stack overflow but neither worked for me, the google vision one and the zebra crossing one(ZXing) can somebody please help me? It shows an irritating whitescreen, I tried these in versions 4.4.4 and 4.1.2. HEre's my code, I'm currently using the Zxing one.

Here's my class where number of buttons are lineup. From here I go to the class where the scanner is, so I can scan the item, and then from there I will do make the other feature. For now my goal is to be able to Scan QR Codes and get its input. I've found some examples on how to get the input so it's not a problem. btu yeah It's not showing!

**Normal.java**

```
public class Normal extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button suite, normal, room1, room2, room3, room4, room5, room6, room7, room8, room9, room10;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase1;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;


    //FIREBASE AUTH FIELDS

    DatabaseReference mSearchedLocationReference;
    DatabaseReference mSearchedLocationReference1;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_normal);

        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        //FIREBASE
        mFirebaseDatabase1 = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Rooms");



        //FIREBASE PINPOINT

        //DRAWER LAYOUT
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        //navigation Drawer
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_menu);
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                    case (R.id.nav_logout):
                        Intent accountActivity4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), login1.class);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(accountActivity4);
                        break;


                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        //Navigation Drawer

        //ASSIGN ID's

        room1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.room2);
        room2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.room3);
        room3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.room4);
        room4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.room5);
        room5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.room6);
        room6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.room7);
        room7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.room8);
        room8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.room9);
        room9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.room10);
        room10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.room11);

        //ASSIGN ID's
        suite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        normal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        suite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent next = new Intent(Normal.this, Suite.class);
                startActivity(next);

            }
        });

        normal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent next1 = new Intent(Normal.this, Normal.class);
                startActivity(next1);


            }

        });


        room1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Normal.this, room2.class));


            }
        });

        room2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });

        room5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Normal.this, room5.class));
            }
        });



        mSearchedLocationReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { //attach listener

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { //something changed!


               for (DataSnapshot locationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  String location = locationSnapshot.getValue().toString();



                  Log.d("Locations updated", "location: " + location); //log
                    if ( location.equals("Green")){

                        room1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }else if ( location.equals("Red")){
                        room1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                    }
                    else{
                        room1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { //update UI here if error occurred.

            }
        });
        mSearchedLocationReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { //attach listener

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { //something changed!


                for (DataSnapshot locationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String location = locationSnapshot.getValue().toString();



                    Log.d("Locations updated", "location: " + location); //log
                    if ( location.equals("Green")){

                        room2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }else if ( location.equals("Red")){
                        room2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                    else{
                        room2.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { //update UI here if error occurred.

            }
        });


    }

}

whenever i click room1, it won't got to the room2 class where I put the scanner:
```

**room2.class**

```
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class room2 extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
    private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_room2);
    }

    public void scan(View view){
        zXingScannerView =new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(zXingScannerView);
        zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        zXingScannerView.startCamera();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

**Here's my manifest, it's got services-vision since I have been trying the two, but yes permission for camera was indeed requested.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chanty.hoteltwoway">



    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        <activity android:name=".login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Room" />
        <activity android:name=".Suite" />
        <activity android:name=".Normal" />
        <activity android:name=".rooms.room1" />
        <activity android:name=".rooms.room2" />
        <activity android:name=".rooms.room3" />
        <activity android:name=".rooms.room5" />
        <activity android:name=".rooms.room6" />
        <activity android:name=".rooms.room7" />
        <activity android:name=".rooms.room8" />
        <activity android:name=".rooms.room10" />
        <activity android:name=".suites.suite1" />
        <activity android:name=".suites.suite2" />
        <activity android:name=".suites.suite3" />
        <activity android:name=".suites.suite4" />
        <activity android:name=".suites.suite5" />
        <activity android:name=".suites.suite6" />
        <activity android:name=".suites.suite7" />
        <activity android:name=".suites.suite9" />
        <activity android:name=".suites.suite8" />
        <activity android:name=".suites.suite10" />
        <activity android:name=".login1" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity1" />
        <activity android:name=".login2" />
        <activity android:name=".Room1" />
        <activity android:name=".Normal1" />
        <activity android:name=".Suite1" />
        <activity android:name=".suprooms.suproom1" />
        <activity android:name=".suprooms.suproom2" />
        <activity android:name=".suprooms.suproom3" />
        <activity android:name=".suprooms.suproom4" />
        <activity android:name=".suprooms.suproom5" />
        <activity android:name=".suprooms.suproom6" />
        <activity android:name=".suprooms.suproom7" />
        <activity android:name=".suprooms.suproom8" />
        <activity android:name=".suprooms.suproom9" />
        <activity android:name=".suprooms.suproom10" />
        <activity android:name=".supsuites.supsuite1"></activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="barcode"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Lot's of depencies, since yeah I have been testing out things since day 1
Here's my gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chanty.hoteltwoway"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.7.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-service
```

I tried downgrading the zebra crossing dependencies according to some sources so it might work. but yeah, it didn't work, can you guys help me figure out what I did wrong with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting another project. Build from the very heart of your program. The github tutorials gave you source codes to try right? Test those first. And then from there learn how they implemented it and then slowly apply it to your program. Here's a good [source](https://github.com/memotiur/Android-ScannerProject-QR-Barcode-/tree/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/gdgbangla/scannerproject) to start with.